# Kill an object in java

Tags: java, jmx, destroy

I am currently using JMX to manage and monitor a huge migration process which is executed within a Java class.

I would like to be able to abort and kill the process when I needed, e.g. customer/time required, or some dead loop happens within a single migration.

Here, we call abort a gracefully way to kill a thread by setting up a boolean flag and once every loop will check the flag first and then decides whether to proceed or not. This has been implemented without any issue.

However, I am having troubles with kill the thread. My colleague had suggested me to override the finalize() method and try to kill it within it. However, what I have found online is this method will not be able to destroy the object and it is recommned to be called by GC but the user instead.

I guess the theory is OK that as long as the object is destroyed, no more process will be able to happen. I am just not sure whether this is able to be implemented in JAVA or not.

Also, I would like to know, is there any other ways that you guys can give me a hint.

Would be very appreciate your help.

P.S: by relating to JMX, doesn't mean it really has to do with JMX, it just I would like this killing command is coming from the JMX console client.

Comment: You talk about "killing an object" and "kill the process". you say you are killing the thread and then you say you are having trouble with it? Is the problem that the object stays in memory (and why would that be a problem) or that it is actually still working? 
Please be a bit more specific about what you do and don't and I am sure you will get answers.

Comment: Stop saying 'kill' because you don't need to kill anything. Once you exit out of the loop (per your third paragraph), the thread will stop, and it should be garbage collected at that point. If this is not the case, then please describe what evidence you have that the thread is still running.

Comment: Thanks Fredrik, sorry for my poor English description about the problem which brought so many troubles. Anyway, what I really mean is try to 'kill' an instance of a class which in the middle of doing something. The instance may get stuck in some circumstances, and I hope an invocation from JMX to get rid of the instance to stop the stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit hard to understand what you are saying, but I don't think that `finalize` is going to be any help.

- A live thread (i.e. one that has been started and has not yet terminated) is reachable by definition, and therefore won't be garbage collected.  So adding a finalize method to it won't have any affect.
- If the object you are talking about is not the thread, adding a finalize probably won't help either:

  - If the thread's runnable (or whatever) has a reference to the object, that will stop it from being garbage collected.
  - If it doesn't, and the object does become unreachable, the `finalize` method won't run until after the GC has decided to collect the object ... and that may never happen.
  - Even if the `finalize` method did get called, what could it do?  You've *already told* the thread to shut down ... and nothing has happened.

The real problem here seems to be that the thread is not responding to your "graceful shutdown" flag.

- I'd try to fix this by using `Thread.interrupt()` and `Thread.isInterrupted()` rather than a custom flag.  This has the advantage that an interrupt will also unblock things like `Thread.sleep` `Object.wait` and certain I/O operations.
- If the thread is blocked trying to talk to some external service via a socket or pipe, you could unblock it by closing the socket and/or stream.  This of course assumes that your shutdown code can get its hands on the reference to the Socket or Stream object.
- If those approaches failed, I'd consider pulling the plug on the entire application by calling `System.exit()` ... if that's a reasonable thing to do.
- If you are totally desperate (and a little bit insane) you could consider using the deprecated `Thread.abort()` method.  But there is a distinct possibility that that would leave your entire application in a broken and unresponsive state.  So I would **NOT** recommend this approach.

The other possibilities to consider are:

- that the Thread has actually responded and exited, but your shutdown code didn't notice,
- that the Thread died before you tried to shut it down it, and your shutdown code didn't notice,
- that the Thread is deadlocked, or
- that there is some long running (but not infinite) loop in the runnable needs to be modified to check the "you die now" flag more often.

Some of these things you could be diagnosed by attaching a debugger and taking a thread dump.

---

I think you said that you saw advice to the effect that it was a BAD IDEA to call `System.gc()`.  This is good advice.

Comment: Stephan, your explanation is really helpful, and thanks very much. It's my bad not describe my problem clearly in the first place. What I would like to achieve is: There is an instance of a class is doing a job which is quite time-consuming, and in some certain circumstances it may get stuck. I would like my JMX to get rid of the instance to stop the stuck.
Appreciate you point out that a finalize() will not help.
Also, I really don't care graceful kill for this instance at all, it's a spring bean, so I guess if just ditch it and the spring container will new another one for me.

Comment: And it's a very large system that I cannot shut done the instance, and that's also why I have to do all this migration task lively. I worried my process if get stuck would severely affect the whole system. As a result, I want a way to kill this instance or stop the process if anything goes crazy.

Comment: @Featheast - unfortunately, if none of the good options work, you are stuck with only the bad ones.  I'd focus on figuring out why the processes are getting stuck ... and fixing that problem.  In general, there simply is NO WAY to (safely) kill a thread that is not cooperating.

Comment: Yep, that's actually the way finally we choose to go: by making the process more robust to avoid any chance of stucking. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You should perform certain task in `finally` which you want to perform when method exits in any condition. Most preferable example people give about this is cosing database connection.

Yes it is recommended to leave Garbage Collection on JVM.

JVM takes care of destrying objects.